# Adding child to Tree using LinkedLists to store the value of Nodes

Tags: java, data-structures, tree

Ok so i want to implement a tree, of which the values of the children of each node are stored in a LinkedList. I have the following Code so far:

```
class Tree {

        class Node {
            int value;
            LinkedList<Node> children = null;

              Node(int value) {
                  this.value = value;
              }
        }

        public Node root = null;

        public void setRoot(Node root) {
            root = this.root;
        }

        public Node getRoot() {
            return root;
        }

        public void addChild(Node parent, Node child) {

        }
}
```

Where I struggle is finding a way to add a child to this structure. I have looked for sites using a similar way to store the data of each node in LinkedLists but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Why do you want to store the child into LinkedList of Node?

Comment: Shouldn't the child structure be of type `Tree`?  So that you can create a recursive Tree data structure.

Comment: @sc0der its an exercise given by my university, why you would do it like that idk. I haven't found`any articles etc doing it this way.

Comment: @Sid yes that would make sense, unfortunately i have to work with the tempelate and the Structure was given like that.

Comment: So every node has N other nodes?

Comment: yes exactly, the only stuff i found was about binary trees but that doesnt imply here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
 static class Tree {
        static class Node {

            int value;
            LinkedList<Node> children;

            Node(int value) {
                this.value = value;
                this.children = new LinkedList<>();
            }

            // Override equals to detect node equality based on the value
            @Override
            public boolean equals(Object o) {
                if (this == o) {
                    return true;
                }
                if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
                    return false;
                }

                Node node = (Node) o;

                return value == node.value;
            }

            @Override
            public int hashCode() {
                return value;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return value + "";
            }
        }

        public Node root = null;

        // Assign the root like this not like yours which was not correct
        public void setRoot(Node root) {
            this.root = root;
        }

        public Node getRoot() {
            return root;
        }

        public void addChild(Node parent, Node child) {
            // Check if the root is null and parent not null then add child to the root
            if (root == null && parent != null) {
                root = parent;
                root.children.add(child);
                return;
            }

            // if the parent equals root then add to the root's child
            if (parent.equals(root)) {
                root.children.add(child);
                return;
            }

            // add recusively
            addRecur(root, parent, child);
        }

        private void addRecur(Node parent, Node p, Node child) {
            // base condition to the recursion
            if (parent == null) {
                return;
            }

            // if the parent equals to p then add to child
            if (parent.equals(p)) {
                parent.children.add(child);
                return;
            }

            // loop over every child and check if equals p if not do recursion
            for (Node node : parent.children) {
                if (node.equals(p)) {
                    node.children.add(child);
                    return;
                }
                addRecur(node, p, child);
            }
        }

        // print the tree
        public void print() {
            ArrayDeque<Node> queue = new ArrayDeque<>();
            queue.add(root);
            while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
                Node current = queue.poll();
                if (!current.children.isEmpty())
                    System.out.print("Parent: " + current + ", child: ");

                for (Node node : current.children) {
                    if (!queue.contains(node)) {
                        System.out.print(node + " ");
                        queue.add(node);
                    }
                }

                if (!current.children.isEmpty())
                    System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
```

, Calls from `main` function

```
    static public void main(String[] args) {
        Tree tree = new Tree();
        Tree.Node root = new Tree.Node(1);
        tree.addChild(root, new Tree.Node(2));
        tree.addChild(root, new Tree.Node(3));
        tree.addChild(root, new Tree.Node(4));
        tree.addChild(root, new Tree.Node(5));

        tree.addChild(new Tree.Node(5), new Tree.Node(6));
        tree.addChild(new Tree.Node(5), new Tree.Node(7));

        tree.addChild(new Tree.Node(6), new Tree.Node(8));
        tree.addChild(new Tree.Node(6), new Tree.Node(9));
        tree.addChild(new Tree.Node(6), new Tree.Node(15));

        tree.addChild(new Tree.Node(9), new Tree.Node(11));
        tree.addChild(new Tree.Node(9), new Tree.Node(10));
        tree.addChild(new Tree.Node(9), new Tree.Node(12));

        tree.print();
    }
```

, `output`

```
Parent: 1, child: 2 3 4 5
Parent: 5, child: 6 7
Parent: 6, child: 8 9 15
Parent: 9, child: 11 10 12
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this code should work:

```
class Node {
    int value;
    LinkedList<Node> children = null;

    Node(int value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.children = new LinkedList<Node>();
    }

    public void addChild(Node child) {
        this.children.add(child);   
    }
}
```

and the function will look like this:

```
public void addChild(Node parent, Node child) {
    parent.addChild(child);
}
```